# Why are both out_file = open(to_file, 'w') and out_file.write(in_data) necessary?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I'm studying python with the book Learn Python The Hard way and I'm on exercise 17. This is the code:

```
1 from sys import argv
2 from os.path import exists
3
4 script, from_file, to_file = argv
5
6 print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

9 in_file = open(from_file)
10 indata = in_file.read()
11
12 print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)
13
14 print "Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file)
15 print "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL- C to abort."
16 raw_input()
17
18 out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
19 out_file.write(indata)
20
21 print "Alright, all done."
22
23 out_file.close()
24 in_file.close()
```

My question is why are both of these lines necessary. I get the why the 1st line is used but what about the second one 2nd one. To me it seems like the code theoreticaly should work the same way if we deleted the 2nd line. Can someone help me understand this?
out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)

Comment: Huh?  How could the *actual writing of data into the file* be optional?

Comment: one line opens the file the other writes to the file object? or am I not understanding your question correctly here? also may I suggest not studying from this book given that `python 2.7` is reaching end of life Jan 1 2020. if you are new to python it makes sense to start from python3

Comment: The two lines you are asking about perform two different tasks. It is like asking why do I need both a fork and a spoon for dinner. Well, it depends on what kinds of food you are eating.

Comment: technically you can just use your hands for dinner

Comment: As already suggested, you should really start with Python 3. Some parts of the code you pasted here are no longer considered good practice (you should use `with open...` now). You might also have a look at https://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints

Comment: Please _please_ listen to @ThierryLathuille. LPTHW was fine in its time, but its time is over. The fact that it's still being recommended for new programmers is a disgrace, and leads to terrible idioms being repeated time and time again. Python2 is dead, and LPTHW should die along with it.

Answer (score 0):

The second line basically overwrites the contents of the file(to_file), since the mode of operation is write mode, or it creates a new file if it doesn't exist. out_file herein is a file object via which you can perform file operations.
Guessing by your assignment's objective, you are basically copying(writing) to another file, which is why the second line is mentioned.

you could also follow another variant-

````py
with open(to_file,'w') as out_file:
```out_file.write(indata)


the latter will automatically close the file object, thereby preventing any errors
````

Comment: `write` doesn't overwrite the contents of the file, it writes starting at the position of the cursor.  Opening the file in write mode is what deletes the files contents.